# In SharePoint 2007, how can I include some common items in a list, and some unique ones for each instance of the list?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I've created a series of meetings in SharePoint 2007.  All meetings have a common "base" agenda, but each meeting will have its own unique agenda items.

Is there a way to implement that in SharePoint?  If I set the agenda items to be "series items", I'm not able to deviate from that list for individual meetings.  That's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a list that includes multiple content types.  You can define custom content types at a site level and they will be available within that site and all sub sites.  You can enable content types on a list or library and include multiple content types for that list or library.  You can also have a content types in several lists and libraries.

Content types can inherit from one another as well.  So, you could have a "Base Agenda" content type and have other content types inherit from that.  Content types go beyond just metadata and deal with behavior as well.  You can assign workflows to a content type and in MOSS you can assign policies (e.g., expiration policy) to content types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472236.aspx